# Add video to the app or youtube API?

Tags: android, android-listview, youtube, android-youtube-api

I am currently developing an app where I need to play a video which is on YouTube. Is it advisable to download the video, put it in my project and then play using a videoview or play directly using the Youtube player?

Also, if the preferred option is by playing using the Youtube player, is there any way I can play it as one of the item in a listview?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to merge the video file into your application because it would heavily increase the size of the APK. Have a look at the [YouTubePlayerView](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView) - this is exactly what you need.